# Replace Text In File Using Windows Prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I know there have been previous posts about this but none of them have worked for me. I want to do a find and replace string in a text file using the windows command prompt. No parameters, all hard coded. Here is what I have so far:
..........

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set SEARCHTEXT=oldtext
set REPLACETEXT=newtext

for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %A in ( C:\in.txt) do (
set string=%A 
echo  set string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT% >> C:\out.txt)
```

..............
This code just writes "set string:oldtext=newtext" to out.txt for each line in in.txt. 
How can I get it to actually replace oldtext with newtext? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Test this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "SEARCHTEXT=oldtext"
set "REPLACETEXT=newtext"

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("C:\in.txt") do (
set "string=%%A"
set "string=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT%!"
>>"C:\out.txt" echo !string!
)
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the `echo`.

It is there for testing the code without really destroying anything.
If the output is what you need, just remove it.

EDIT: ah wait - there is a logical failure in the code. It should obviously look like:

```
...
for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%A in ( C:\in.txt) do (
 set string=%%A 
 set string=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT%! 
 echo !string!>> C:\out.txt
)
```